# FTP output redirect to a file on my linux box using shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ftp

I am looking for a Bash script to redirect a simple `ls` command output to a file on my Linux box from my FTP Server.

Here follows the step by step commands to illustrate what I am looking to script. The FTP site can be accessed without a user/password, so i am entering user as `anonymous` and password as blank when prompted.

```
ftp <FTP_SERVER>
Connected to <FTP_SERVER> (IP_ADDRESS).
220 Microsoft FTP Service
Name (<FTP_SERVER>:root): anonymous
331 Anonymous access allowed, send identity (e-mail name) as password. 
Password:
230 Anonymous user logged in.
Remote system type is Windows_NT.

ftp> ls /Outgoing/Artemis/incremental/Hashes-1492870261.zip

227 Entering Passive Mode (10,37,108,77,5,87).

125 Data connection already open; Transfer starting.

04-22-17  07:11AM               227634 Hashes-1492870261.zip
226 Transfer complete.
```

I need the output of the command 'ls' command I am executing to be saved in a file on my linux box.

Here is the script i have:

```
ftp FTP_SERVER <<EOF >outputfile

quote USER anonymous

quote PASS 

prompt noprompt

ls -la /Outgoing/Artemis/incremental/Hashes-1492870261.zip

quit

EOF
```

when i execute this i get a login failed error.

```
sh -x test.sh

+ ftp FTP_SERVER`

Password:

Login failed.

local: /Outgoing/Artemis/incremental/Hashes-1492870261.zip: No such file or directory
```

I used some random password as a test instead of blank (null) which I used previously, but still get the same error. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turn interactive mode off:

```
ftp -i -n FTP_SERVER <<EOF >outputfile
user <user> <password>
binary
ls -la .
quit
EOF
```

Comment: @AbhinandanAithal If that answered your question, you are supposed to accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You might get on better with `lftp`:

```
lftp -e 'ls -l someFile.zip; quit' -u USER,PASSWORD FTPSERVER   > ls.txt
```

where all the words in capitals need replacing by your own values.

---

Or you could try with `curl`:

```
curl ftp://FTPSERVER --user USER:PASSWORD
```